# How to strip html tags in string then escape the plain string and put the escaped string into html tags back

Tags: jquery, html, strip

I wanted to strip html tags then escape plain string and put back the escaped string back into html tags , for that i have tried :

```
var aa = "<p>hi testing & </p>";
var bb = $(aa).text();
var cc = escape(bb);
var dd = aa.replace(bb, cc);
```

dd gives me the output `"<p>hi%20testing%20%26</p>"` , but the problem is when i have multiple html tags in string  for eg: `aa ="<p>hi testing & </p><p> failed & </p>"` its not working.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close! [`jQuery.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is quite handy for this. When you pass it a function it'll replace the text content of selected elements with the result of the function:

```
var aa  = "<p>hi testing & </p><p> failed & </p>"
  , $aa = $(aa).text(function(_, content) { return escape(content); })
;

console.log($aa);
// => [<p>​hi%20testing%20%26%20​</p>​, <p>​%20failed%20%26%20​</p>​]
```

Comment: hi , it will not work if aa = "<div>"<p>hi testing & </p><p> failed & </p></div>". Is it possible to do using jquery else i will have write recessive function.

Comment: Looks like you're right. Yes, I think you'll have to do this recursively.